# Bootstrap 3 nested columns not full width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an issue with bootstrap 3 when I nest columns. The nested columns are not full width of the containing column. They are only about two thirds the width of . The  are set to width 33.33% in bootstrap. I have tried different elements.

```
<section id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="highlight-prim">Privilage on a card</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <span>See our many partners where your card can used:</span>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>A1 Driving for life</li>
              <li>A1 Driving for life</li>
              <li>A1 Driving for life</li>
              <li>A1 Driving for life</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>A1 Driving for life</li>
              <li>A1 Driving for life</li>
              <li>A1 Driving for life</li>
              <li>A1 Driving for life</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>A1 Driving for life</li>
              <li>A1 Driving for life</li>
              <li>A1 Driving for life</li>
              <li>A1 Driving for life</li>
            </ul>
          </div>      
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-4">
        <h3 class="highlight-sub">Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>            
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This is a screenshot with the padding to the  unset. Although the nested columns do get longer they still fall short of the full width.

http://www.upload.ee/image/3759755/Untitled-2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctrl+f found me 17 div tag , an extra `</div>` tag
http://dpaste.com/1500911/

Comment: yes thanks, there was indeed. Unfortunately the problem still persists that the nested dont take up the full width

Comment: They dont take up the full space because their nested in a col-md-7 / col-md-4 offset1

Comment: The nested need to add up to 12, which they do. Bootstrap gives them a width of 33.33% which is correct. But they dont fill the full space of the  col-md-7

Comment: I dont seem to be getting that here is the link to the demo on what I am working on http://www.iipc.eu/

Comment: When i viewed the source, it showed me 81 div =D, unclosed tags can cause so many weird anomalies.

Comment: The extra div you are finding I think is the the line <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->

Comment: media="screen"
.list-unstyled {
padding-left: 0;
list-style: none;
}  after deleting padding left. it worked for me - http://www.upload.ee/image/3759749/anomaly.png

Comment: Yes thought that also, but if you look closely it still falls short of the full width. It does get bigger not quite all the way.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. That worked I must have introduced that when testing something else :-)